# Android 2.3 maintain ListView position when using Fragments

Tags: java, android, listview, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have been trying to find a solution to this. How do I maintain the `ListView` position when I am using `Fragments` and someone rotates the device.

The rotation itself resets everything and it's back to 0 again. I can get it to work with the multiple examples when I am using normal `Activities`, but how do I do it when I am inside a specific `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you do not call setAdapter() again on rotation or after any operation you do. Always call notifyDataSetChange() and your list will remain at the same point

Other workaround can be that you save the position of the current list item and call setSelection(position) for what you want to keep

Answer (score 0):

You d have to store some kind of view tag or position number in a bundle on your on pause and in your on resume check if the value is null. If it's not set the list view to said position.

Comment: You'd have to create the bundle in your activity and make it static.